# How to get just one item of related entity in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I have "Person" entity that has a property "Status" and this property is an OneToMany relationship in Doctrine.

```
/**
 * 
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\My\Bundle\Entity\Status", mappedBy="person")
 * 
 **/
protected $status;
```

What I need to do is to display in my view is just the last status.

How can I get just the last status in my twig view? Is there something like, for exmample, {{ person.status.last }} ?

Or should I query the last status in my controller and pass it to view as another var?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it exactly like this `{{ person.status.last.someField }}` to echo a `someField` property of last status (in natural query order) for person object.

This is possible because person.status is a Doctrine Collection which has methods like `first` or `last`. You can check [this](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.0/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.Collection.html) for more information.